# Laravel form does not defined

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel.I try to build form with laravel collective.I update laravel for collective by `composer require laravelcollective/html` then add in app.php `Collective\Html\ HtmlServiceProvide::class` in providers add add

```
Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class
```

in aliases
But it displays errors in these three updated things in providers & aliases(Collective\Html\FormFacade type not defined) and in browser it displays error(form not defined)
Any help?please

Answer (score 0):

First check that you capitalized `Form` Then try to clear config cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If you still have a problem you can go to `composer.json` and check that `laravelcollective` required then try to run this:
`composer update`

Answer (score 0):

add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [
  // ...
  'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  // ...
],
```

add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
  'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
// ...
],
```

then hit blow command in your working directory.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
```